# Factoring to find Residue

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to find the residue of this around the unit circle, $\frac{z}{(z+\frac{\beta}{2}(z^2+ 1))^2}$.  All I want help with is how to factor the bottom into a form I can work with.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

$$z+\frac{\beta}{2}(z^2+ 1) = \frac{\beta}{2} z^2 + z + \frac{\beta}{2}$$

To factor, find the zeroes:

$$z_{\pm} = -\frac{1}{\beta} \pm \sqrt{\frac{1}{\beta^2} -1}$$

The polynomial being squared is then

$$\frac{\beta}{2} (z-z_+)(z-z_-)$$

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the quadratic equation to find the roots...
They are
$$\frac {-1 \pm \sqrt{1-\beta^2}} \beta$$
with multiplicity 2 each.